# Java arrays and scope

Tags: java, arrays, scope

I writing an application where i use an array within a class. This array is declared globally outside of any method scope so that all of the objects methods will be able to access the data. However, when i assign an object to a index that object is only available as a part of the array in that particular method. Any other method trying to read that index of the array gets a nullpointerexception.

Some code illustrating my usage:

```
Account[] accounts = new Account[8000];


public void addAccount() {


    cli.printMessage("Welcome to the account add wizard.");
    String holdername = cli.getInput(entername);
    int accountnr = Integer.parseInt(cli.getInput(enternr));
    BigDecimal accbalance = new BigDecimal(cli.getInput(enterinitialbalance));

    accounts[accountnr] = new Account(holdername, accountnr, accbalance);
    String accountinfo=accounts[accountnr].number + " " + " " + accounts[accountnr].holder + " " + accounts[accountnr].balance;
    cli.printMessage(accountinfo);

}
```

Adding the account works all the way, this do not when ran from the same instance of this class:

```
public void getAccountinfo() {

    int accountnr = Integer.parseInt(cli.getInput(getinfo));
    String accountinfo=accounts[accountnr].number + "" + "" + accounts[accountnr].holder + accounts[accountnr].balance;
    cli.printMessage(accountinfo);
}
```

Is this due to scope or is it due to me confusing instance and class variables? Might it be something completely different?

The error i get is a nullpointer exception at

```
        String accountinfo=accounts[accountnr].number + "" + "" + accounts[accountnr].holder + accounts[accountnr].balance;
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: What's do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: It should be fine - please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. (You should also consider using camelCase for your variable names for clarity.)

Comment: what value does accountnr have in getAccountinfo()

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the second method on the same object and that you're requesting the same 'accountnr'?

Comment: Scope is determined during compile time, not runtime (possibly unless you use reflection). So a NullPointerException during runtime cannot be linked to scope.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, trying to rebuild it in a shorter version made me see that problem, so special thanks to Jon Skeet! The solution can be read as a comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getAccountInfo` you let the user input a number X.
If the array 'cell' at X was not previously set via `addAccount`, `accounts[X]` is `null` and thus `accounts[X].number` correctly bombs out.

Comment: You are correct, and i found the error. The application is a cli application. When the user had entered some input and finished their "task" i called the menu rendering method again. The problem was that the class that held the code i pasted(Account managing class) was instanciated inside of that method. Thus creating a new Account managing object for each task. Moving it to a global object within that class made it all work.